# Physics-based dynamic audio generation in games

Tags: physics, audio

I wonder if it is possible to generate audio dynamically without any (!) audio assets, using pure mathematics/physics and some input values like material properties and spatial distribution of content in scene space. What I have in mind is something like a scene, with concrete floor, wooden table and glass on it. Now let's assume force pushes the glass towards the edge of table and then the glass falls onto the floor and shatters. The near-realistic glass destruction itself would be possible using voxels and good physics engine, but what about the sound the glass makes while shattering? I believe there is a way to generate that sound, because physics of sound is fairly known these days, but how computationaly costy that would be? Consumer hardware or supercomputers? Do any of you know some good resources/videos of such an experiment?

Comment: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/harmonicfluids/
http://www.behance.net/gallery/Procedural-Rain-Sounds-BSc-Major-Project/3620167
This stuff mostly exists in academic studies.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to do. Do you want to create sound by literally controlling the speakers, and outputting frequencies by yourself? Because I think you could get similar level of realism just by composing your sound output out of smaller sound files with varying volume.

Comment: This is a really chatty question. The answer is yes, it's possible, but making it all sound perfectly awesome is an ongoing challenge. Wind, impacts, and other sounds are generally figured out to some extent. In addition to the link provided by Arthur, check out http://www.procedural-audio.com/ and http://research.scee.net/files/presentations/develop2010/AudioAnalysis,themissinglink.pdf and http://designingsound.org/2012/06/procedural-audio-an-interview-with-nicolas-fournel/ I'm voting to close though, because you're not asking a specific question. Are you actively trying to synthesize sound?

Comment: The breaking animation could be achieved by Phymec and Bullet 3D
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FIPu9_OGFgc

Comment: I'm voting to close as not a real question. I'm sure this is possible, but it falls under [this mention in the FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask): _"If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."_

Comment: Well, it's possible to answer to the "good resources" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed regularly in the [Game Programming Gems](http://www.gameprogramminggems.com/).

That's probably one of the best resource you can find, here's a quick selection of articles:

- GPG4: 7.6 Controlling Real-Time Sound Synthesis from Game Physics
- GPG6: 6.1 Real-Time Sound Generation from Deformable Meshes
- GPG8 : 6.3 Real-Time Sound Synthesis for Rigid Bodies